# Overlaying elements over HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, html5-video

I am relatively new to CSS and HTML5 and wanted to see how to overlay HTML text or other elements over a video. I inherited and modified someone's code and it appears to work properly when I play around with it on JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/jxavLps5/ but I **can't get it to work right when hosted via my local bottle (WSGI) server**. I have the following HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/container.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="container-module">
        <div class="video-container">
            <div class="title-container">
              <h1>Bug Buck Bunny - Trailer</h1>
            </div>
            <video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">
              <source src="http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" type="video/webm" /> Upgrade browser
              <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type = "video/mp4" /> Upgrade browser
             </video>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My CSS is here:

```
    html, body{
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .container-module {
        border-right: none;
        border-left: none;
        position: relative;
    }
    .video-container {
        position: relative;
        bottom: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: #000;
    }
    .video-container .title-container {
        z-index: 2147483647;
        position: absolute;
        top: 35%;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        color: #ff0;
    }

    .video-container video {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 100;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    .video-container video.fillWidth {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .no-video .video-container video,
    .touch .video-container video {
        display: none;
    }
    .no-video .video-container .poster,
    .touch .video-container .poster {
        display: block !important;
    }
```

No matter what I do, **I can't get the text to appear over the video**. Please note that I had to change the **position** to *relative* instead of *absolute* in the fiddle to get it to work. What am I doing wrong? Any advise appreciated.

Comment: `position: absolute` is working in your fiddle - is there some reason that solution won't do for you? There's nothing wrong with using it in this situation - it's one of the only ways to make one element overlap another. Perfect use case.

Comment: @ingridly Thanks for commenting. What I mean is `.video-container video {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;    
}` will not work in my fiddle. Regardless, even my fiddle as it is does not produce the same result on my server.

Comment: You can use Source Tab on Developer panel in Chrome browser to check whether you're getting the files right (Check the content). It could be that your server is not delivering them properly. Also you can check that the CSS is applied properly to the elements, by inspecting them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for taking the time to respond. Upon further inspection I found that console was spitting the following error:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type
>   text/html

I had let my server guess mime-type for static contents since it has appropriately done in the past, but it appears it wasn't doing it right.

To fix the problem, I rewrote my static delivery function which I am attaching here in case someone runs into the same later:

```
@welcomeApp.route('/static/<filepath:path>')
def send_static(filepath):
        currentLocation = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        staticPath  = currentLocation + '/static/'
        if '.mp4' in filepath:
            mime = 'video/mp4'
        elif '.webm' in filepath:
            mime = 'video/webm'
        elif '.css' in filepath:
            mime = 'text/css'
        else:
            mime = None
        return static_file(filepath, root=staticPath, mimetype= mime )
```